# Sending Parameter to Method - NSTimeInterval

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, parameters

I am trying to send a NSTimeInterval into a method which will run on the main thread from a method running on the background thread.  Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
Sending 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double') to parameter of incompatible type 'id'
```

here's my code - any idea what's going wrong?

First, I setup my NSTimerInterval, and call performSelectorOnMainThread:

```
NSTimeInterval delayBetweenIntAdsNSTimeInterval = [responseStringTimeBetweenAds doubleValue];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startTimerForAds:) withObject:delayBetweenIntAdsNSTimeInterval waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and here is the code for my method I am calling:

```
-(void)startTimerForAds:(NSTimeInterval)intervalBetweenAds {
}
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong with that?

Thanks,

**UPDATE**

I call:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startTimerForAds:) withObject:@(delayBetweenIntAds) waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and here is that method:

```
-(void)startTimerForAds:(NSInteger *)intervalBetweenIntAdsInteger {
}
```

but over that call (over the object), XCode shows:

```
Illegal type 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *') used in a boxed expression
```

and it shows over [intervalBetweenIntAdsInteger doubleValue]:

```
Bad receiver type 'NSInteger *' (aka 'int *')
```

Comment: what is the responseStringTimeBetweenAds ? string?

Comment: Yes, responseStringTimeBetweenAds is a string with an integer in it, so I use doubleValue to convert that integer to a double

Comment: NSTimeInterval is not an object. Try NSNumber.

Comment: @DigiMonk - are you saying send an NSNumber and convert it to a NSTimeInterval in the method I send a NSNumber to?

Comment: Yes, because NSTimeInterval is not an object. See my answer, hope it works

Comment: Great answer, will remove mine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSTimeInterval is not an object. Try NSNumber, that should do it :

```
NSTimeInterval delayBetweenIntAdsNSTimeInterval = [responseStringTimeBetweenAds doubleValue];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startTimerForAds:) withObject:@(delayBetweenIntAdsNSTimeInterval) waitUntilDone:NO];


-(void)startTimerForAds:(NSNumber *)intervalBetweenAds {

     NSTimeInterval i = [intervalBetweenAds doubleValue];

}
```

UPDATED because of your UPDATE:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startTimerForAds:) withObject:@(delayBetweenIntAds) waitUntilDone:NO];

-(void)startTimerForAds:(NSNumber *)intervalBetweenAds {
     int i = [intervalBetweenAds intValue];
}
```

Comment: @DigiMong - this doesn't now work when I change it to NSIntegers - just updating original question with appended bit

Comment: So it is not possible to make it send NSInteger?  Seems silly, but ok - will have to work with NSNumbers - which also seems inefficient, having to create yet another variable!

Comment: You don't have to create an extra variable, you can just use NSNumber's methods. Dig deeper if you are concerned about efficiency.